# Same constant is defined with GET but undefined with POST - express, mongo, react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, body-parser

I'm following a React tutorial, in which I am building a basic blog in MERN stack.

In this particular case, in my `Server.js` file I am attempting a `POST` request to MongoDB. It identifies the collection & JSON object using URL parameters, alters the object & returns a new constant equal to the new object.

The issue is that the `const`  equal to the object found is showing to be not defined. However, I cannot figure out why that would be. Another function using a `GET` request with the same `const` (each are local to their respective functions) works as designed with no error regarding defining the `const`.

```js
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb';

const app = express();

// also tried to use express' built in bodyparser, same error
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// working GET req function using the same const
app.get('/api/articles/:name', async (req,res) => {
    try {
        const articleName = req.params.name;

        const client = await MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017', { useNewUrlParser: true });
        const db = client.db('my-app-db');

// this is the const in question, equal to object found
// based on name param passed in URL
        const articleInfo = await db.collection('articles').findOne({ name: articleName });
        res.status(200).json(articleInfo);

        console.log(articleInfo);

        client.close();
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({message: 'Error connecting to db', error});
    }
    
});

// non working POST req function, using the same const
// added slash to front of path as it was originally missing, still 
// getting error
app.post('/api/articles/:name/upvote', async (req,res) => {
    try {
        const articleName = req.params.name;

        const client = await MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017', { useNewUrlParser: true });
        const db = client.db('my-app-db');
        
        // gets error for being undefined at Server.js 32:5
        const articleInfo = await db.collection('articles').findOne({ name: articleName });
        await db.collection('articles').updateOne({ name: articleName },{
            '$set' : {
                upvotes: articleInfo.upvotes + 1,
            }, 
        });
        
        // this is updated article sent as response 
        const updatedArticleInfo = await db.collection('articles').findOne({ name: articleName });

        res.status(200).json(updatedArticleInfo);
        client.close();

    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({message: 'Error connecting to db', error});
    }
})

app.listen(8000, () => console.log('Listening on port 8000'));
```

This is the error exactly as its received in Postman

> ReferenceError: articleInfo is not defined
>
> at C:\Users\oduboise\Desktop\sandbox\react-full-stack\my-app-backend\src/Server.js:32:5
>
> at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\oduboise\Desktop\sandbox\react-full-stack\my-app-backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>
> at next (C:\Users\oduboise\Desktop\sandbox\react-full-stack\my-app-backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
>
> at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\oduboise\Desktop\sandbox\react-full-stack\my-app-backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
>
> at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\oduboise\Desktop\sandbox\react-full-stack\my-app-backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>
> at C:\Users\oduboise\Desktop\sandbox\react-full-stack\my-app-backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
>
> at param (C:\Users\oduboise\Desktop\sandbox\react-full-stack\my-app-backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:354:14)
>
> at param (C:\Users\oduboise\Desktop\sandbox\react-full-stack\my-app-backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:365:14)
>
> at Function.process_params (C:\Users\oduboise\Desktop\sandbox\react-full-stack\my-app-backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:410:3)
>
> at next (C:\Users\oduboise\Desktop\sandbox\react-full-stack\my-app-backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)

This is the response from the successful `GET` request, as a JSON object

```
{
"_id": "5ec60f1390d2ce923cdb0e41",
"name": "what-react",
"upvotes": 0,
"comments": []
}
```

This is also my first time asking a question in StackOverflow, usually i'm able to figure it out/find it. So any question formatting tips would be appreciated as well

Comment: please check `articleName` inside post method. what's the value you are getting in it

Comment: The only error I see is that the POST route does not start with a slash.

Comment: @VivekDoshi It should just be the URL param, in this case "what-react". However, I can't seem to find a way to get the value of the const returned or logged based on the individual requests.

Comment: @EduardoRocha Definitely a good catch, I figured that would've done it. But still getting the same error with the updated `/api/articles/:name/upvote`. That also being said, the response still seems to show Server.js:32:5, no matter what changes are made to Server.js...

Comment: @okd_v i think its the line after, please console.log articleInfo, it will be undefined, you are probably sending names that are not in the database and updating without checking if it's not null first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check article exists , by adding if condition to avoid "undefined" error

```
const articleInfo = await db.collection('articles').findOne({ name: articleName });
console.log('articleInfo ===>',articleInfo);
if(articleInfo){

            console.log('article upvotes==',articleInfo.upvotes);

            await db.collection('articles').updateOne({ name: articleName },{
                    '$set' : {
                        upvotes: articleInfo.upvotes + 1,
                   }, 
            });
}else{
   res.status(404).json({message:"Article not found"});
}
```